# Changing default keybinding in yhat's Rodeo IDE

Tags: python, key-bindings, rodeo

To comment out a block in Rodeo the [docs](http://rodeo.yhat.com/docs/#keyboard-shortcuts) state to do `ctrl + /`. But on my machine thats not working, so I want to change a single keysetting. Where I am able to do this in Rodeo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit key-bindings in preferences http://rodeo.yhat.com/docs/#preferences

Changing the key bindings should avoid the use of `ctrl + /`, but if you just want to change a single setting, as far as I know, it's not possible. It's hardwired in https://github.com/yhat/rodeo/tree/master/src/browser/ace . You can write some code and build your own IDE if necessary.

Comment: There i can change the keybindings to default, emacs or vim. But i want to configure the default bindings

Comment: Changing the key bindings should avoid the use of `ctrl + /`, but if you just want to change a single setting, as far as I know, it's not possible. It's hardwired in https://github.com/yhat/rodeo/tree/master/src/browser/ace . You can write some code and build your own IDE if necessary. @Manuel

Comment: Ahh okey thank you ! I hope they will implement some kind of stuff in the future and going write my own IDE :)